# Issued Token Authentication over HTTP

Tags: wcf, azure, token

Is it possible to do Issued Token authentication over HTTP?

The scenario that we are faced with is an HTTPS request from client to server. Authentication is performed here and a token is issued. We are now however faced with the need to route this request to one of multiple endpoints using a generic message passing implementation. The problem we are faced with is that this endpoint is over HTTP as it is an Internal endpoint in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at implementing virtual tokens and multi-factor authentication in general.